# Target sdk version changed to 29, but not working in android 10 and 9

Tags: android, decompiler, apktool

After decompiling with apk tool, I changed targetsdk version to 29(and minsdk version to 19), and build and signed it again.
This is apktool.yml file:

```
isFrameworkApk: false
packageInfo:
  forcedPackageId: '127'
  renameManifestPackage: null
sdkInfo:
  minSdkVersion: '19'
  targetSdkVersion: '29'
sharedLibrary: false
sparseResources: true
unknownFiles: {}
usesFramework:
  ids:
  - 1
  tag: null
version: 2.4.1
versionInfo:
  versionCode: '1'
  versionName: '1'
```

and this is AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="air.id181apeke">
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="....">
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="Oxford - Starter" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name=".AppEntry" android:screenOrientation="user" android:theme="@style/Theme.NoShadow" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="autoOrients" android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data android:name="fullScreen" android:value="true"/>
            <meta-data android:name="uniqueappversionid" android:value="9de9b08c-60fa-4ecc-86ea-983d2105693d"/>
            <meta-data android:name="containsVideo" android:value="false"/>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="true"/>
</manifest>
```

What's wrong here buddies?

Should I add something or some files?

Cheers

Comment: please mention the issue clearly whether app is not loading or app crashes like that, if any error occurs please post log also.

Comment: ah ok. after installing, says: ... app keeps stopping

Comment: did you receive any exception in logcat ?

Comment: no, nit any exception

Comment: @satuser any idea?

Comment: are you using any api call while loading the app ??